# Is there a way to find the updated pod when we do pod update in post_install

Tags: cocoapods

when we run

pod update podname

Wanted to catch the pod/pods(or related targets) updated in post_install
Is this possible?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve by that?

Comment: trying to to use Rome plugin so Rome builds all the pods when we do a pod update
wanted to modify it to build only that is required i guess the best way is to make duplicate of podfile.lock in pre_install and then on post_install check the updated pods was wondering if there is a better way? Then use that result to build only that is required.

Comment: Looks like this does the job https://github.com/Subito-it/PodBuilder Thanks